# Angular 7 : Eliminating indexing of column names in the UI

Tags: angular

I have implemented a dynamic table in angular 7. I am display the column headers and records vertically. If you notice the columnheaders are hardcoded in the component. I currently have around 57 columns that I am rendering and issue that I forsee is when a new column is introduced in the server or the sequence of the column changes. The current UI code looks very tied by index i.e magic numbers. Is there a better way to handle the UI rendering.

UI

```
<table class="fundClassesTable table-striped" border="1">
  <tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames">
    <th class="tableItem bold">{{ c }}</th>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let f of data">
         <ng-container *ngFor="let s of data1;">
             <ng-container *ngIf="f.Id == s.LegalParentClassId">  
      <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[0]">{{f.Description}}</td>
      <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1]">{{f.AuditSummary}}</td>
      <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td>
    </ng-container>
     </ng-container> 
  </ng-container>

  </tr>
  </table>
```

Component

```
public ColumnNames: string[] = ['Legal Class Name', 'Last Edited' , 'Legal Class ID',''];
```

JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/sm7fzjhq/3/

JSON

```
[{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class B","AuditSummary":"skeeling Jun 11, 2018","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":11166,"FundId":5508,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":"","ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":3,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":"12 M,0.03|","LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class A","AuditSummary":"skeeling Jun 11, 2018","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":11167,"FundId":5508,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":"","ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":3,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":"12 M,0.03|","LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class A","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 04, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji May 28, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"kweigand Jan 16, 2019","Id":13713,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":"10,19,7","ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":2,"SubVotingName":"Yes","SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":{"Description":"Class A","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 05, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji May 28, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"kweigand Jan 16, 2019","Id":28444,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":4,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":"10,19,7","ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":2,"SubVotingName":"Yes","SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":13713}},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class D","AuditSummary":" ","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":13714,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":"","ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":null,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class C","AuditSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"fblack Nov 21, 2018","Id":13715,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":"","ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class B1","AuditSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"fblack Nov 21, 2018","Id":13716,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":"","ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":22,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"72","LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class B","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 04, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji May 28, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"rmenon Jun 04, 2019","Id":13717,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":"","ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"TestRanjit100","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 04, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":28424,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":2,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"USD","OtherCurrencyName":"","ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":null,"RedsFrqncyName":null,"RedsNoticeDays":null,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":null,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":null,"LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":null,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":null,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null}]
```

Serverside columnnames

```
Dictionary<string, string> legalFundClassColumnNames = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"Legal Class Name", "Description"},
                {"Last Edited", "AuditSummary"},
                {"Legal Class ID", "Id"}
            };
```

Markup

```
  <div *ngIf="LegalFundClasses && LegalFundClasses.AllTerms && LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassColumnNames">
        <table class="fundClassesTable table-striped">
            <tr *ngFor="let c of LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassColumnNames | keyvalue">
                    <th> {{ c.key  }}</th>

                    <ng-container *ngFor="let f of LegalFundClasses.AllTerms; let i=index;">
                        <td class="tableItem"> {{f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel[c.value] }}</td>
                            <td class="tableItem">
                            <div *ngIf="EditMode[f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.Id]">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" style="float: left;"
                                    (click)="reviewClicked(f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.Id,1)">Review
                                    Terms</button>
                                {{f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel[c.value]}}
                            </div>
                        </td> 



                         <td colspan=i class="tableItem"  *ngIf="i<1"></td>

                          <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.Id]" class="tableItem">
                            {{f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel[c.value]}}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.Id] " class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist style="height: 29.5px;"
                                [(ngModel)]="f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.CurrencyId" [defaultItem]="defaultItem"
                                class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="LegalFundClasses.Currencies"
                                [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>
                        </td>

                    </ng-container>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want horizontal scroll table rather than vertical?

Comment: You might want to censor any sensitive info from that fiddle.

Comment: Yes I have removed the sensitive information now.

Comment: Nope scrolling isnt the issue. I want the same layout that is displaying the records horizontally including column names but dont want to use hardcoded idexes to identify columns as the columns could change in order or new columns could get added on the serverside code. I need the UI to be independent of the server implementation

Comment: @Tom, please,not repeat question. tip: if you see your profile, you see the questions you has done

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you'll have better luck with a better column model, something like:

```
public ColumnNames: {header:string, prop:string}[] = [ 
                                   {header: 'Legal Class Name', prop: 'Description'},
                                   {header: 'Last Edited', prop: 'AuditSummary'},
                                   {header: 'Legal Class ID', prop: 'Id'}];
```

then you can use the improved model in your table to dynamically display data:

```
<tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames">
    <th class="tableItem bold">{{ c.header }}</th>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let f of data">
      <td class="tableItem" >{{f[c.prop]}}</td>       
    </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Now if your data changes, you're at least working with typescript code instead of html template. You could even store this column definition on your server and update it without ever redeploying / modifying your front end code.

you could in theory extend this model to include other things like classes, cell templates to display, or other things like sort keys, width definitions, etc. Let your imagination run wild.

Here's a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/o6y49v25/

Comment: I have just updated the post with serverside implementation of columnnames and it works if I am only displaying normal td in a loop but my markup isnt that straightforward. Each td contains a control. How do I control that

Comment: You’re honestly probably better off using a table component built and maintained some where else. But the way to accomplish this is by using the ng template directives that allows you to provide custom reusable templates.

Comment: Can I do something like this on every td   <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c.value == 'Description'"> {{f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel[c.value] }}</td>

Comment: Or even better cant I do       <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c.value == c.value"> {{f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel[c.value] }}</td>

Comment: no, you can't do that, you need to use a template directive.  I'll work something up in a few but strongly consider using an existing table component.

Comment: Thanks Bryan . I am looking forward for your example

Comment: The above solution doesn’t work for my requirement and looking for an appropriate solution. What I am thinking is *ngIf=“c.value==“Description”. I do this for all tds with respective fields .

Answer (score 1):

Apply sorting to column before rendering.

```
constructor(){
  this.ColumnNames = Object.keys(this.data[0]).sort();
}
```

Try this:[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khushbu07/5y9841dn/11/)